# Dynamic Form Input Array Not Copying to csv file in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, csv

I have a multipage form with the ability in certain areas to dynamically add inputs for the user to put in more jobs, education, etceteras.

I'm having two problems:

1. Problem 1

   The first is I don't think I'm getting the array values in the proper manner, even though I think I have that part working because I can print them on the screen
2. Problem 2

Whenever I try to push the values that I am echoing to the screen, all that gets printed to the .csv file is `Array`

PHP:

```
$unitLevelPosition = $_POST["unitLevelPosition"];
$oectaUnit = $_POST["oectaUnit"];
$unitPresident = $_POST["unitPresident"];


$csvData = var_dump($unitLevelPosition) . "," . var_dump($oectaUnit) . "," . var_dump($unitPresident);

$fp = fopen("formData.csv", "a");

if($fp)
    {
        fwrite($fp, $csvData . "\n");
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

JS:

```
var i = 0;
function addUnitInvolvement()
{
    i++;
    var unitInvolvementDiv = document.createElement("div");
    unitInvolvementDiv.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="four-lines" name="unitLevelPosition[]" placeholder="Position/Committee">  <input type="text" class="four-lines" name="oectaUnit[]" placeholder="Unit"> <input type="text" class="four-lines" name="unitPresident[]" placeholder="Unit President"> <input type="date" class="four-lines" name="unitYear[]"> <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeUnitInvolvement(this)">';
    
    document.getElementById("unitLevelInvolvement").appendChild(unitInvolvementDiv);
}

function removeUnitInvolvement(unitInvolvementDiv)
{
    document.getElementById("unitLevelInvolvement").removeChild(unitInvolvementDiv.parentNode);
};
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" class="scholarshipForm">
        

<!-- start of page 3 content begins  -->

            <div id="page3-content">

                <p class="subtitleDirection">List offices held or committees you have been involved with a the Unit level. Please include the name of the Unit President at the time of your involvement.</p>

                <div class="clearFix"></div>

                <div class="input-group" id="unit-level-involvement">
                    <label id="unitInvolvement">Unit Involvement *</label>
                    <div id="unitLevelInvolvement">
                        <input type="text" class="two-lines-textbox" name="unitLevelPosition[]" id="unitLevelPosition_1" placeholder="Position/Committee" onBlur="this.placeholder='Position/Committee'" onFocus="this.placeholder=''" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />
                        <input type="text" class="two-lines-textbox" name="oectaUnit[]" id="oectaUnit_1" placeholder="Unit" onBlur="this.placeholder='Unit'" onFocus="this.placeholder=''" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />
                        
                        <div class="clearFix"></div>
                        
                        <input type="text" class="two-lines-textbox" name="unitPresident[]" id="unitPresident_1" placeholder="Unit President" onBlur="this.placeholder='Unit President'" onFocus="this.placeholder=''" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />
                        <input type="date" class="two-lines-textbox" name="unitYear[]" id="unitYear_1" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />
                        <input type="button" value="+" onClick="addUnitInvolvement()" />
                    </div>
                 </div><!-- end of unit-level-involvement div-->
                
  
            
            <button type="button" id="nextButton-page-3" disabled="disabled" onClick="nextPage()">Next</button>
            <button type="button" id="backButton-page-3" onClick="previousPage()">Back</button>
            </div><!--end of page3 content -->
            
        <!--    page 3 content ends -->
           
           
            <input type="submit" id="finalSubmit" disabled="disabled" />
            </div><!--end of page 6 content -->
                
                    <div class="clearFix"></div>

    </form><!--endForm-->
```

Comment: var_dump prints its result (like echo does), but it does not return it, so you can't use it to build that string.  Try print_r($oectaUnit, true) instead (the "true" sais to return the string instead of printing it).  See if that answers your questions

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, that seems to have done the trick but I've run into a bit of a snag, with all my other regular single inputs its printing them once cell after another horizontally, these are going vertically down the page.  Do you know how to amend this?Array 
( 
    [0] => Head 
) 
 Array
( 
    [0] => Wellington 
) 
 Array
( 
    [0] => theodore 
)